# Howto: workaround of close_fds=True and redirect stdout/stderr on windows

Tags: python, windows, subprocess

I had a problem: using Python 2.7, it was not possible to create a subprocess using

```
subprocess.Popen([.......], close_fds=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, ...)
```

On windows, because of limitations. The use of `close_fds` was needed in my case, as I did not wanted the subprocess to inherit from already opened files file-descriptor. This was called in a library, which meant I had no control over already opened- file descriptors (`N` flag).

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue19575), which was fixed on [Python 3.4+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0446/)

The question I had was: How do I use subprocess without getting

> close_fds is not supported on Windows platforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr

Answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**This issue is fixed on Python 3.7+ by default**

This is definatly a tricky hack: answer is to iterate through already opened file descriptors, just before using the `subprocess` module.

```
def _hack_windows_subprocess():
    """HACK: python 2.7 file descriptors.
    This magic hack fixes https://bugs.python.org/issue19575
    by adding HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT to all already opened file descriptors.
    """
    # See https://github.com/secdev/scapy/issues/1136
    import stat
    from ctypes import windll, wintypes
    from msvcrt import get_osfhandle

    HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT = 0x00000001

    for fd in range(100):
        try:
            s = os.fstat(fd)
        except:
            continue
        if stat.S_ISREG(s.st_mode):
            handle = wintypes.HANDLE(get_osfhandle(fd))
            mask   = wintypes.DWORD(HANDLE_FLAG_INHERIT)
            flags  = wintypes.DWORD(0)
            windll.kernel32.SetHandleInformation(handle, mask, flags)
```

Here is a sample that would crash without it:

```
import os, subprocess
f = open("a.txt", "w")
subprocess.Popen(["cmd"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
f.close()
os.remove(f.name)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "stdin", line 1, in module
>
> WindowsError: [Error 32] Le processus ne peut pas accÚder au
>   fichier car ce fichier est utilisÚ par un autre processus: 'a.txt'

Now with the fix:

```
import os, subprocess
f = open("a.txt", "w")
_hack_windows_subprocess()
subprocess.Popen(["cmd"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
f.close()
os.remove(f.name)
```

Works.

Hope i helped

Comment: In Python 2.7 on Windows, you can explicitly open a file as [N]on-inheritable, e.g. `f = open("a.txt", "wN")`. In Python 3, this is the default.

Comment: This is right, the above example is only used when the program has no control over the files that have been opened before (e.g. an API)

Comment: Also, in 3.7 (still in beta) subprocess gets around this problem using a `PROC_THREAD_ATTRIBUTE_HANDLE_LIST` to constrain which inheritable handles actually get inherited.